# Codeblocks debugger failed

Tags: codeblocks

I have ust started using debugger but it shows this error on pressing move to cursor on codebocks.

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: C:\anand\software\installed\CodeBlocks\dp\
Adding source dir: C:\anand\software\installed\CodeBlocks\dp\
Adding file: C:\anand\software\installed\CodeBlocks\dp\bin\Debug\dp.exe
Changing directory to: C:/anand/software/installed/CodeBlocks/dp/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Starting debugger: C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/anand/software/installed/CodeBlocks/dp/bin/Debug/dp.exe
failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with not being able to start the debugger and it turned out I forgot to install it in the first place. Check whether you have gdb present in your system -- if you're running on Windows and using MinGW then look into C:/MinGW/bin for gdb.exe

Comment: If you don't have an answer, try puting your suggestion into the comment section